# How to handle NaNs while binning with numpy add.reduceat?

Tags: python, numpy, binning

I'm using the `numpy` `reduceat` method for binning data. Background: I'm processing measurement data sampled at high frequencies and I need to down-sample them by extracting bin means from bins of a certain size. Since I have millions of samples, I need something fast. In principle, this works like a charm:

```py
import numpy as np
def bin_by_npreduceat(v, nbins):
    bins = np.linspace(0, len(v), nbins+1, True).astype(np.int)
    return np.add.reduceat(v, bins[:-1]) / np.diff(bins)
```

The Problem is: NaNs can occur (rarely but it happens). Consequence: the whole bin will be NaN since I use `np.add`:

```py
v = np.array([1,np.nan,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,7,3,2,5,6,9])
bin_by_npreduceat(v, 3)
Out[110]: array([nan,  5.,  5.])
```

Anybody know how I can fix this? `np.nansum` unfortunately has no `reduceat`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a `masking` based method -

```
# Mask of NaNs
mask = np.isnan(v)

# Replace NaNs with zeros
vn = np.where(mask,0,v)

# Use add.reduceat on NaNs skipped array to get summations
# Use add.reduceat on the mask to get valid counts
# Divide them to get final output
out = np.add.reduceat(vn, bins[:-1])/np.add.reduceat(~mask, bins[:-1])
```