# A more efficient way to resizing Numpy Array into different size chunks

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry I am not sure how to put the title more accurately.

I have an array which I would like to evenly split into 3 arrays, then each array will have a different size which is the downsampled version of the original array via averaging.

Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(100)
bins = [5, 4, 3]
split_index = [[20, 39], [40, 59], [60, 80]]
b = []
for count, item in enumerate(bins):
    start = split_index[count][0]
    end = split_index[count][1]
    increment = (end - start) // item
    b_per_band = []
    for i in range(item):
        each_slice = a[start + i * increment : start + (i + 1) * increment]
        b_per_band.append(each_slice.mean())
    b.append(b_per_band)
print(b)
```

Result:

> [[21.0, 24.0, 27.0, 30.0, 33.0], [41.5, 45.5, 49.5, 53.5], [62.5,
>   68.5, 74.5]]

So I loop through bins, find out how much increment is for each step. Slice it accordingly and append the mean to the result.

But this is really ugly and most importantly has bad performance. As I am dealing with audio spectrum in my case, I would really like to learn a more efficient way to achieving the same result.

Any suggestion?

Comment: to clarify: 1) you take slices given by `split_index` from an array `a` 2) for each slice, you calculate 'sub-slices' with lengths given in `bins`, 3) for each sub-slice, you take the average. Is that correct?

Comment: (1)(2) Correct. (3) For this particular case, each slice has a size of 20, which I would like to downsample to one of the bins, for example 5, this will mean every 4 samples I will take the average of those 4 and append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option using `np.add.reduceat`:

```py
a = np.arange(100)
n_in_bin = [5, 4, 3]
split_index = [[20, 39], [40, 59], [60, 80]]
b = []
for i, sl in enumerate(split_index):
    n_bins = (sl[1]-sl[0])//n_in_bin[i]
    v = a[sl[0]:sl[0]+n_in_bin[i]*(n_bins)]
    sel_bins = np.linspace(0, len(v), n_in_bin[i]+1, True).astype(np.int)
    b.append(np.add.reduceat(v, sel_bins[:-1])/np.diff(sel_bins)))
print(b)
# [array([21., 24., 27., 30., 33.]) array([41.5, 45.5, 49.5, 53.5]) array([62.5, 68.5, 74.5])]
```

Some notes:

- I changed the name `bins` to `n_in_bin` to clarify a bit.
- using the floor division, you discard some data. Don't know if that's really important, just a hint.
- the thing that should make this code faster, at least for large array sizes and 'chunks', is the use of `np.add.reduceat`. From my experience, this can be more efficient than looping.
- if you have `NaN`s in your input data, check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160558/how-to-handle-nans-in-binning-with-numpy-add-reduceat).

**EDIT/REVISION**

Since I'm also working on [binning stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389710/how-to-efficiently-bin-multiple-dependent-variables-to-a-common-independent-vari) at the moment, I tried a couple of things and ran `timeit` for the three methods shown so far, 'looped' for the one in the question, 'npredat' using `np.add.reduceat`, npsplit using `np.split` and got for 100000 iterations an avg time per iteration in [µs]:

```
a = np.arange(10000)
bins = [5, 4, 3]
split_index = [[20, 3900], [40, 5900], [60, 8000]]
-->
looped: 127.3, npredat: 116.9, npsplit: 135.5
```

vs.

```
a = np.arange(100)
bins = [5, 4, 3]
split_index = [[20, 39], [40, 59], [60, 80]]
-->
looped: 95.2, npredat: 103.5, npsplit: 100.5
```

*However*, results were slightly inconsistent for multiple runs of the 100k iterations and might differ for other machines than the one I tried this on. So my **conclusion** would be so far, that differences are marginal. All 3 options fall within the 1µs < domain > 1ms.

Comment: Yeah, this is also what I found comparing different methods. It seems no clear advantage of each one with sample size smaller than 100000. Larger than that this seems more efficient. I don't know why as I see the operations being pretty linear.

Comment: right, maybe there is some memory optimization going on, that also depends on the current state of the memory - but that's just guessing. Maybe the question is also suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing looks very weird to me, including the setup, which could probably use a different approach, making the problem much simpler.

However, using the same approach, you could try this:

```
b = []

for count, item in enumerate(bins):
    start = split_index[count][0]
    end = split_index[count][1]
    increment = (end - start) // item

    b_per_band = np.mean(np.split(a[start:start + item * increment], item),axis=1)

    b.append(b_per_band)
```

Comment: hmmm. This is correct. But I timed a 8000 samples array splitting into 3x2000 chunks. Using np.split() was actually slower, with the previous method takes 107us vs 125us.